# Distinct classes for each row in views-table

Tags: views, 6

Is there a code that I add to my views style tables file that will give me distinct classes for each row in a views-table? or is there a module? I am working in Drupal 6

Comment: distinct classes? normally class is used to specify common aspects of styles for reusability... why not use id instead?

Comment: I used group by so i have five tables on the page and each table has five rows with five different classes but they are repeated in each table. I want to be able to style a specific row in each table.

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas:

1) with **:nth CSS selector** you can reach every row you want with your style rules. For example the third row can be selected with the selector:

```
.table-class .tr:nth(3) td { background: red; }
```

2) with **jQuery**

Comment: Thanks, I tried the nth Css selector, the only problem is that I used the group by option in the views-table so i have 5 tables on the page and it  makes every third row in each table red. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: 1) if your tables are identified by an id, you can easily solve with: `#table-id .tr:nth(3) td { background: red; }`

2) you can use the nth selector also for the tables. example: `#container .table-class:nth(2) .tr:nth(3) td { background: red; }`

REMEMBER: nth isn't crossbrowser. read this article to solve that: [Making nth-child Work Everywhere](http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere)